# Hover effect on StackLayout

Tags: telerik, nativescript

I trying to do a buttonImage with text, but failed. After that I using another method to show out, it look nice but left hover effect, isn't possible add hover into stacklayout?

```
  <StackLayout tap="tapevent" col="1" row="0" horizontalAlignment="center" cssClass="padding-list" tap="jl">
              <Image src="~/images/drawable-xhdpi-v4/basketball.png"   />
              <Label text="abc" cssClass="text-align-center" />
          </StackLayout>
```

I try using :pressed and :hover in css but also not take any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a background-image on the button, can happen in the CSS file the following way:

```
button {
    background-image: url("~/background.jpg");
}
```

About the :hover pseudo selector, it will be great if you can add your input in the [discussion in GitHub](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/50).